# how to debug build expo react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm currently creating react native mobile app with expo.

When I use expo start : no problem.

When I build app and when I click on a specific link : crash and app mobile is closing.

I installed bugsnag but nothing  go up in notification.

How to debug this ? Where can I find some logs ?

Thanks for your help :)